# Computing residue involving Bernoulli numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, bernoulli-numbers

I would like to show the following:

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{e^{nz}}{(1-e^{-z})^{m+1}}\right)=\binom{n+m}m$$

Basically I have to show that the $z^{-1}$ term in $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(nz)^k}{k!}\right)\left(\frac1z +\frac12 +\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i-1}B_i}{(2i)!}x^{2i}\right)^{m+1}$$

is given by $\binom{n+m}m$. I am not sure about how to simplify the Bernoulli numbers in the products and sums.

Comment: I should give some context here. This is basically a calculation in algebraic geometry about the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch formula applied on $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^m}(n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Residue identity for function composition: $ \operatorname{Res}(f; h(a)) = \operatorname{Res}((f∘h)h'; a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830152/residue-identity-for-function-composition-operatornameresf-ha-oper):

$$
\operatorname{Res}_{z=a}\left(f(h(z))h'(z)\right)=\operatorname{Res}_{w=h(a)}(f(w))\;.
$$

In your case we can take $h(z)=\mathrm e^z$ and

$$
f(w)=\frac{w^{n-1}}{\left(1-w^{-1}\right)^{m+1}}=\frac{((w-1)+1)^{n+m}}{(w-1)^{m+1}}\;.
$$

Then the residue of $f\circ h$ at $a=0$ is the residue of $f$ at $h(a)=1$, which is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(x+1)^{n+m}$, which is indeed $\binom{n+m}m$.

(A similar result is shown at [Residue of composite functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640832/residue-of-composite-functions), but only for simple poles.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is simpler than I thought!

Comment: @lEm: If a result is that simple, it usually has a correspondingly simple derivation :-)

Comment: That's a very useful identity for calculating residues.  I'm surprised I've never seen it before.

Comment: @RandomVariable: Same here :-)