# Confusion in computing the residue of Veneziano Amplitude function: a general statement for computing a composite function residue.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

**Premise:** I'm an undergraduate student, so I'm only considering the math perspective of the following problem and not its physical relevance nor significance.

I'm currently studying Euler's Gamma function $\Gamma(z)$, and I came across one of its applications to string theory in some notes. I am having trouble in understanding a statement, which looks wrong to me.

Consider Veneziano Amplitude function, defined as:

$$A_V(s,t) := \frac{\Gamma(-1-\alpha's)\Gamma(-1-\alpha't)}{\Gamma(-2-\alpha's-\alpha't)}$$

where $\alpha'$ is a (real) parameter and $\Gamma$ function is defined in the domain:

$$D:=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z \neq 0,-1,-2,...\}$$

I already know that $Res_{z=-n} \Gamma(z) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\le0}$.

My purpose is to calculate $Res_{\alpha's = n}\Gamma(-1-\alpha's)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge -1}$. My notes do as follows:

$$Res_{\alpha's = n}\Gamma(-1-\alpha's) = Res_{w = -1-n}\Gamma(w) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

while I consider the correct answer to be (let me call for simplicity $g(\alpha's):= -1-\alpha's$):

$$Res_{\alpha's = n}\Gamma(-1-\alpha's) = \frac{Res_{w = -1-n}\Gamma(w)}{\frac{dg}{d(\alpha's)}|_{\alpha's = n}}= -\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

giving a minus sign not present in the notes. My result comes from a simple theorem on the residual of composite function in the case of simple poles (the only kind of singularities which occur in $\Gamma$ function), which I will not describe because already discussed in the previous question at the link [Residue of composite functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640832/residue-of-composite-functions).

What am I missing? Please let me know whether my answer is incomplete or unclear and I will edit it to a better version. Thank you in advance.